# Calling publishProgress from another method in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to download a file from my server in Android and updating the progress..

On Async method in background I am calling a method that will download the file to my SD card now I would like update the progress hence trying publishProgress("" + progressvalue); which I am not able access from this method. How do I access the publishProgress?

Here is what I am trying:

```
private class FileDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... param) {
            downloadFileToSdCard(param[0], "File" + counter + ".mp4");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
        {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", values[0]);
        }
}
```

downloadFileToSdCard method looks like this:

```
private void downloadImagesToSdCard(String downloadUrl, String fileName)]
{
        FileOutputStream fos;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);
            String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(sdCard, "AppDownload");
            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdir();
            }

            String fname = fileName;
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();

            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            final String contentLengthStr=ucon.getHeaderField("content-length");

            int lenghtOfFile = Integer.valueOf(contentLengthStr);

            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) ucon;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            long total = 0;
            int progress = 0;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {

                total += bufferLength;
                int progress_temp = (int) total * 100 / lenghtOfFile;
                publishProgress("" + progress_temp);
                if (progress_temp % 10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp)
                {
                    progress = progress_temp;
                }
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                int downloadedSize = Integer.valueOf(contentLengthStr);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            fos.close();
            Log.e("Value", "File Saved in sdcard..");
        } catch (IOException io) {
            inputStream = null;
            fos = null;
            io.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }
```

Can somebody help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a good reason for not putting all code from downloadImagesToSdCard directly into doInBackground? It would certainly solve the problem

Comment: @andMarkus: There is no exact reason I am just making the code to look good. That was my last option. I can't use it from the method?

Comment: Structuring your code is a good idea, I'd say you're on the right track. You just need to pass the sdcard method something to report progress with. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triy this:

keep you function inside into AsyncTask Class

```
     private class FileDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... param) {
                downloadFileToSdCard(param[0], "File" + counter + ".mp4");
                return null;
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
            {
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", values[0]);
            }

            private void downloadImagesToSdCard(String downloadUrl, String fileName)
            { 
               //Publish Progress calling code
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that hits me is to simply pass your AsyncTask to your sdcard method. AsyncTask.publishProgress is protected, so as long as your two classes are in the same package, you should be able to call publishProgress from the sdcard downloaded method.

A cleaner/prettier approach would be to define a callback interface such as ProgressUpdater, let the AsyncTask implement it, and have the sdcard method take a ProgressUpdater as a parameter. This interface would typically have a similar or even equal publishProgress method. This however decouples the AsyncTask itself from the rest of your program.